# dist behaves differently in gpuMatrix, how to get the same result?

Tags: r, gpu, distance

I am trying to optimize euclidian distance calculation between a set of points,
when runing dist on a simple matrix, with x on first column and y on the second, like this:

```
m <- matrix(c(3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6) , ncol=2)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    4    2
[3,]    5    3
[4,]    6    4
[5,]    7    5
```

I get the following result:

```
dist(m)
         1        2        3        4
2 1.414214                           
3 2.828427 1.414214                  
4 4.242641 2.828427 1.414214         
5 5.656854 4.242641 2.828427 1.414214
```

I am particularly interested in the first column, which has the distance of each point to the next point. However if I use gpuR package and convert this matrix to a gpuMatrix the result is completely different and I don't know how to interpret it, can some one explain or point me in the right direction, I can't find useful documentation on this function on this library or examples:

```
m2 <- gpuMatrix(m)
dist(m2)[]
         [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.000000 1.414214    0    0    0
[2,] 1.414214 0.000000    0    0    0
[3,]      NaN      NaN    0    0    0
[4,] 2.828427      NaN    0    0    0
[5,] 4.690416      NaN    0    0    0
```